# Specify host on DB connections

Tags: laravel

I have database.php config like this:

```
...
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'read' => [
            'host' => [
                env('SLAVE_HOSTNAME_1'),
                env('SLAVE_HOSTNAME_2'),
                env('SLAVE_HOSTNAME_3'),
                env('SLAVE_HOSTNAME_4'),
            ],
        ],
        'write' => [
            'host' => env('MASTER_HOSTNAME_1'),
        ],
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
],
...
```

And i want to get `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` from each read host. But i found no solutions in documentation. May be somebody already solve problem like this?

edit: I think that separating hosts is not a solution in my case, because hosts list in mysql.read.host can be edited.

Comment: specify a separate connection, that will have the specific host, and use that connection to query data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i can't just separate the connections, and i just create separate connection:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector;
use Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Throwable;

public function getStatuses(): array
{
    $hosts = Config::get('database.connections.opv_backend.read.host');

    $data = [];
    foreach ($hosts as $host) {
        try {
            $connection = $this->getNodeConnection($host);

            $replicationStatus = $connection->select(DB::raw('SHOW SLAVE STATUS'));
            $data[$host] = array_first($replicationStatus);

            $connection->disconnect();

        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            if (isset($connection) && $connection instanseof MySqlConnection) {
                $connection->disconnect();
            }
            // Process errors
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

protected function getNodeConnection(string $hostName): MySqlConnection
{
    $config = Config::get('database.connections.mysql');

    $connection = static function () use ($hostName, $config) {
        $config['host'] = $hostName;
        return (new MySqlConnector())->connect($config);
    };

    return new MySqlConnection($connection, $config['database'], $config['prefix'], $config);
}
```

Works fine for me.
**This is just an idea, for production using need more details.**